# Convert Iqueryable to DataTable

Tags: c#-3.0

I am using Linq-To-Sql, how do I convert an Iqueryable type to DataTable type. I could not find any method call in the framework that did it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you could just loop through your results and insert them into a DataTable as [shown here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034%28VS.80%29.aspx), but why would you want to?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was really helpful. I want to populate a grid from the Datatable and make the grideditable. When I do so with an Iqueryable datasource, it does not let me edit the data.

Comment: @Purusartha: You should consider using `LinqDataSource` instead.  There's an excellent example here on how to make editable grids using it http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/16/linq-to-sql-part-5-binding-ui-using-the-asp-linqdatasource-control.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a more efficient approach: Creating a DataTable From a Query (LINQ to DataSet): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx